# changing php array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this very very basic code

```
  foreach ($formatted_results as $result) {
          $result['profile_pic']="joe";//set all values to joe
              var_dump( $result['profile_pic']);//prints joe
        }
  foreach ($formatted_results as $result) {

              var_dump( $result['profile_pic']);//does not print joe!
        }
```

where formatted_results is an array containing other arrays. Now as you can see, I am modifying in the first loop the value of every array within formatted_results to contain the name joe, and then I am printing that to make sure and sure enough, the print of the first loop returns "joe"

However, the value I set is not persisting somehow, as when I loop that same array again to check the inner values of its own arrays, it gives me the old value.

The code is exactly as I am displaying it here, there is nothing in between. I am guessing there is something about pointers that is eluding me here.

Comment: Because in the other foreach you do not set "joe" as value for `$result['profile_pic']`

Comment: You need to use reference operator `&` to reflect the changes made to the array elements. `foreach($formatted_results as &$result)` makes it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value is not set to the actual `array`, rather assigned to the current element which is not available outside the loop. You need to set the value to the actual `array` you are looping through. Try -

```
foreach ($formatted_results as &$result) {
    $result['profile_pic']="joe";//set all values to joe
}
```

[foreach - Pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Perfect, thank you (you answered so fast stackoverflow is making me wait before I set it as the answer) But care to explain to me what the & does exactly? And in which cases shoudl I use it?

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi please go through - http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code :

```
    foreach ($formatted_results as $k =>  $result) {
          $formatted_results[$k]['profile_pic']="joe";//set all values to joe
              var_dump( $formatted_results[$k]['profile_pic']);//prints joe
        }
  foreach ($formatted_results as $result) {

              var_dump( $result['profile_pic']);//does not print joe!
        }
```

$result is not gonna save data to $formatted_results